# Ajax fail not triggered, while error does

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following js code on a button click:

```
$("#processCategories").click(function () {
    console.log('HERE');
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxUrl, // point to server-side PHP script 
        data: {action: 'processCategories'},
        type: 'post',
        done: function () {
            console.log('SUCCESS');
            //location.reload();
        },
        fail: function (msg) {
            console.log('FAIL');
        },
        always: function (msg) {
            console.log('ALWAYS');
        }
    });
});
```

In my php file, I've added the next line:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not found');
die();
```

I've also tried it with forbidden.

So, console logs: `HERE`, but not `FAIL` and neither the `ALWAYS`

I am using this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) says:

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

If I rewrite these to to `error` and `complete`, both of them are running.

What do I miss?

**UPDATE**

`.done` is not runs also. `success` does.

Comment: What is the version of jQuery you are using?

Comment: It's in the question. 1.11.3

Comment: Does Network tab in developer tools or firebug is showing that request returns 404 response?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are confusing jqXHR methods with $.ajax options.

`$.ajax` will **return** a jqXHR object and that will have a fail *method*, so you could do:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxUrl, // point to server-side PHP script 
    data: {action: 'processCategories'},
    type: 'post'
}).fail(function (msg) {
        console.log('FAIL');
});
```

`$.ajax` options which take functions for handling success and error conditions are:

- complete
- error
- success

jqXHR methods which takes functions for the same are:

- done
- fail
- always
- then
- success (deprecated)
- error (deprecated)
- complete (deprecated)

Comment: Thank you, +1, but epascarello was faster.

Comment: @lolka_bolka — Faster? His answer says "answered 3 mins ago" this one says "answered 4 mins ago".

Comment: Corrected, sorry. As you see, I am really tired :)))

Comment: Great explanation. The jQuery.ajax() documentation doesn't do a great job of clarifying the differences, so it's easy to get them mixed up.

Answer (score 4):

They follow the pattern of [jQuery's promises](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) so you need to chain them to the Ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxUrl, // point to server-side PHP script 
    data: {action: 'processCategories'},
    type: 'post'     
}).done(function () {
    console.log('SUCCESS');
    //location.reload();
}).fail(function (msg) {
    console.log('FAIL');
}).always(function (msg) {
    console.log('ALWAYS');
});
```